# How to extract elevation data from ASTER/SRTM?

Tags: qgis, dem

I just want to know if there are any other tools available in QGIS apart from the *Point Sampling* tool to extract elevation data from ASTER/SRTM/CartoDEM (for India) data? When I convert these images to XYZ, I can see 1 to 2m differences in certain points with respect to the *Point Sampling* tool results. More over, the results obtained through point sampling are integers, not decimals like that of the extracted XYZ.